# Getting singular form of homograph words in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, singular

When using `str_singular()` function in Laravel to get a singular form of word 'leaves' it returning 'leaf'.

However I need to get 'leave' word, like in 'leave of absence'.

Comment: Laravel uses doctrine/inflector for singular/plural inflection. As far as I'm aware there's no way for it to natively distinguish between homographs, so you would need to define your own exception cases.

Comment: As @Padarom mentioned, why not just make an exception if this is the only case you need it for?

Comment: I did it explicitly as an exception but, thought there was a solution in these cases

Comment: doctrine/inflector in itself is a piece of marvel my friend. I use it often in my works. Your request is so advanced even an AI has trouble with it. Google can provide understandable translations, but can't singular/plural a sentence. If sentences are predictable, you could make use of laravel's localization -> pluralization functionality. That's as close as it could possibly bring you.